# Angular Material 6.0.1 Tree default opened and expand/collapse all

Tags: angular, tree, angular-material

I'm using the Angular Material Tree in my project.
Is it possible to have the tree opened by default.

And could there be a way to expand/collapse all the nodes at once (eg. with a button)

https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`MatTree`'s treeControl provide a `expandAll` method which you can use to expand all tree nodes, and `collapseAll` to close all tree nodes.

You can can instance of `MatTree` via `ViewChild` and call `expandAll` in `ngAfterViewInit` life hook to make it expand by default.

```
@ViewChild('tree') tree;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.tree.treeControl.expandAll();
}
```

Source example for calling from template:

```
<button (click)="tree.treeControl.collapseAll()">collapseAll</button>
<button (click)="tree.treeControl.expandAll()">expandAll</button>
<mat-tree #tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  ...
<mat-tree>
```

see **[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vx1u5b-x6bovx?file=app/tree-flat-overview-example.html)**.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: For the `expandAll` functionality to work, make sure the `dataNodes` variable of the `TreeControl` must be set to all root level data nodes of the tree.

Comment: @AdityaVikasDevarapalli couldn't get it to work using the standard sample on Angular Material: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmuvwj        Could you help?

Comment: @HobojoeBr here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wmuvwj-qb8kso

Comment: BTW is it possible to add tree-lines for the tree ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I didn't see any options about your expected feature, maybe you can provide your idea to their team. :-)

Comment: @Pengyy help me out on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578743/how-to-make-mat-tree-component-angular-material-6-0-1

Comment: For your example, I had to add dataChange subscription, where I called .expandAll(), to ngAfterViewInit for it to work

Comment: How to expand the first node but not others ?

Comment: If you use mat-tree, there is a problem with dataNodes in TreeControl. Look at below @Pipo answer

Answer (score 13):

In addition make sure that treeControl nodes are set. After loading data you should

```
treeControl.dataNodes = nodes; 
treeControl.expandAll()
```

[See this github issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12170)

Answer (score 1):

**As of September 2023**

It is possible to expand all tree nodes programmatically by calling the `expandAll()` method:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  this.treeControl.expandAll();
}
```

Or collapse them all with the `collapseAll()` method:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  this.treeControl.collapseAll();
}
```