# Importing tree component from angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to import tree component i,e`Tree with partially loaded data` from material.I have followed according to this example [stackblitz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We2EC.png)

I am stuck with this error

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ExistingOfferingsComponent->LoadmoreDatabase]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ExistingOfferingsComponent -> LoadmoreDatabase]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for LoadmoreDatabase!
```

How can i make first matTree(i,e vegetables in the example) to be open by default.something like this.
[image]

Comment: Your edit deleted the stackblitz link

Comment: Here is the stackblits link `https://stackblitz.com/angular/kdepalderex?file=app%2Ftree-loadmore-example.html`

Comment: Expanding is possible. Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286936/angular-material-6-0-1-tree-default-opened-and-expand-collapse-all) for some guidelines. If this should not solve your issue please ask a new question because this is a different issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `LoadmoreDatabase` to the `providers` of your `ExistingOfferings` component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'existing-offerings-component',
    templateUrl: 'existing-offerings-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['existing-offerings-component.css'],
    providers: [LoadmoreDatabase]
})
export class ExistingOfferingsComponent{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I got it,Thank you.